# Update Datagrid cell according to other cells when hit Enter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm using Galasoft's `EventToCommand` as code below to update Line Total cell after user inserts price and quantity.
Please, help me find the appropriate way to make the Line Total changes when I insert the price, quantity and hit Enter. I tried `InputBindings`, but unfortunately didn't work.

Here is the Datagrid XAML from my View:

```
<DataGrid  IsReadOnly="False" x:Name="_StockCardItems"  ItemsSource="{Binding InvoiceDetailsList, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"  CanUserDeleteRows="True" CanUserAddRows="False">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="CurrentCellChanged">
            <gs:EventToCommand PassEventArgsToCommand="True" Command="{Binding CurrentCellChangedCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <DataGrid.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding CurrentCellChangedCommand}"/>
    </DataGrid.InputBindings>

    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Désignation" Width="400" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate  >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=Items.Designation}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Quantité"  Width="150" IsReadOnly="False">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate  >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox  Margin="10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" GotKeyboardFocus="TextBox_GotKeyboardFocus" GotMouseCapture="TextBox_GotMouseCapture" IsReadOnly="False"  Text="{Binding Path=Quantity, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource RemoveDoubleZero}}"  />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn   Header="PU"  Width="150" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox  Margin="10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="False" GotKeyboardFocus="TextBox_GotKeyboardFocus" GotMouseCapture="TextBox_GotMouseCapture"  Text="{Binding Path=UnitePrice, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource RemoveDoubleZero}}"  />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Montant HT"  Width="150" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Path=Line_Total,Mode=TwoWay,ValidatesOnExceptions=True,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, StringFormat=n, ConverterCulture=fr-FR}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Here is the `CurrentCellChangedCommand` excute method in the ViewModel (`SelectedItem` is an EF Entity):

```
private void RecalculateLineTotal()
{
    if (SelectedItem != null)
    SelectedItem.Line_Total = SelectedItem.Quantity * SelectedItem.UnitePrice;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know what happened but now it started to work normally !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started to work normally after sometime. I think that was something extra prevented those Key stroks from working.